# How to send notification to a particular user using Faye Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye, websub

I want to keep different connections to different users just like Node.js with Socket.IO does.

Comment: Have you watched the Faye Railscast episode? http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails/).

It's about sending private message to a specific user. So, it's almost the same.

For this, you can make users subscribe to their own channel (for example, /users/user_id)

```
client = Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
client.subscribe('/users/USER_ID', function (data) { something; });
```

Then, you just have to push data to the user's channel.

```
<% broadcast '/users/USER_ID' %>
  something
<% end %>
```

The broadcast method comes from this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) that you should watch/read if you haven't already done it yet.

Comment: I need to send a notification from Rails Controller Action to a particular user

Comment: I want to be able to push data to the user channel from a controller action (on receiving a get request from outside)---Simon Ninon?

Comment: You should look at this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) (it seems you didn't) as i said in my answer: it learns you the way to use Faye (diffusing data to a channel after a request to the server). Then, you have to make user subscribe to their own channel.

Comment: Instead of USER_ID, I need to replace it with <% current_user.id %>, right?

Comment: Yes: `<%= current_user.id %>` (don't forget the `=`).

Comment: I have tried doing it but to no use, is there any way I could debug the flow.